# Three possible positions of a vertex of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

The coordinates of the point A ,B and C are $(5 ,-1 ,0) , (2,4 ,10) , (6 ,-1 ,4) $ respectively

The point D is such that ABCD is a parallelogram .

Find three possible positions of D

My turn :

The midpoint of ACis $(11/2 , -1 ,2) $
Which the same as the midpoint of BD

Then we can find one position of D

But i do not know how can i get the other two positions ?

Answer (score 1):

The three positions that $D$ may take--call them $D_1, D_2, D_3$--form a triangle such that the midpoints of $D_1 D_2$, $D_2 D_3$, and $D_3 D_1$, are $A$, $B$, and $C$ in some order.

So if you want to extend your process to find the other two points, you would find the midpoint of $BC$, then find the point such that $AD$ shares the same midpoint; and then do the same for the midpoint of $AB$.